# Как редактировать шаблон формы в Битриксе

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте. Может кто сталкивался с таким вопросом и знает как его решить. Сайт на битриксе, собрала пользовательскую форму. И все конечно хорошо, но не могу понять,как изменить внешний вид этих полей, так как стандартные слишком длинные и узкие. Где именно в битриксе можно это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Битрикс у каждого элемента есть свой шаблон. По умолчанию шаблоны используются из "системных" каталогов. 
Чтоб создать собственный в публичном разделе включаете режим правки и наводите курсор мыши на форму. Появится небольшая панель битрикс, на ней будет шестеренка. При наведении увидите меню среди прочего "Копировать шаблон компонента". Нажимаете - внимательно читаете все что будет в появившейся форме.
Если не уберете галку "Перейти к редактированию" то в конце работы этого мастера у ас откроется на редактирование шаблон. Можете править там, можете по ftp (в этой форме в шапке можете подсмотреть путь к файлу).

Советую, изучить курсы битрикс, http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/  контент менеджер и администратор... Это обережет ваш сайт от возможных проблем.

Comment: когда я нажму "Копировать шаблон" и перейду к редактированию, изменения будут происходить на той же странице, где располагается форма? Или создается новая страница? И можно ли в том редакторе задавать внешний вид формы? Ширину, высоту, стиль отображения рамок полей?

Comment: Нет. Если вы укажите копировать шаблон компонента, то будет создана копия шаблона исключительно этого компонента. Страница останется та же.  Можно, но будет не совсем корректно. Поскольку там все же html + php. Правильным будет редактировать по ftp. В том же каталоге где будет лежать этот файл template.php будет лежать (если нет -можно создать) styles.css в нем можете задавать стили. Кроме того, если вам нужны единые стили для полей ввода по всему сайту. Можете редактировать файл template_styles.css в каталоге шаблона сайта..